# adding multiple menu using slickNav

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, slicknav

I'm trying to add 2 menu using `slickNav`. I've successfully created one but if I try to add another, I can't style it separately, I tried using prependTo, but when I stick it like `#menu .slicknav_menu{}` it just hide my nav.

Can't seem to find another solution to this. Please help me out.

here is my default code when I successfully created my nav:

```
.slicknav_menu{
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px){
  header {      
    background-color: #fff;
  }

  #menu {
    display: none;
  }

  .slicknav_menu {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    z-index: 1000;
    right: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;      
  }

  .slicknav_btn{
    background-color: #c9251c;
    margin: 35px 30px 0 0;
  }

  .slicknav_nav{
    background: #c9251c;
    width: 200px;
  }

  .slicknav_nav li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
    width: 200px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ba1e16;
    border-top: 1px solid #d11e14;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .slicknav_nav li a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .slicknav_nav li a:hover {
    color: #000;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  }
}
```

Comment: This might help - https://codepen.io/ComputerWolf/pen/xGdaVJ

Comment: @T.Shah no luck

Comment: i think it's ignoring the prepend here's my js $('#menu').slicknav({
  label: 'MENU',
  PrependTo: '#menu-placeholder'
 

 });